# Call Selector method from another Class - NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsnotificationcenter

I would like to know how I can call the selector which is in another class when notification is posted.I am on tabbarcontroller.

The `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController` are **tab bar items**

```
Inside `FirstViewController` I have the following

-(void)viewdidload
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:)   name:kProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(productPurchaseFailed:) name:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object: nil];

}

- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

    NSString *productIdentifier = (NSString *) notification.object;
    NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", productIdentifier);

    [appDelegate.myDownloadablePoemsArray addObject:productIdentifier];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
}

- (void)productPurchaseFailed:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

    SKPaymentTransaction * transaction = (SKPaymentTransaction *) notification.object;    
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {    
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" 
                                                         message:transaction.error.localizedDescription 
                                                        delegate:nil 
                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] autorelease];

        [alert show];
    }

}
```

The above code is working fine. Now what the issue is, I want to call the same selector method from my another view say for example I have a view controller named `SecondViewController`, in that I am adding the same notification observer.

but the selector method is not called in the `FirstViewController`.

Inside `SecondViewController` I have the following

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:)   name:kProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(productPurchaseFailed:) name:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object: nil];

}
```

But I want to call the selecor methods from `FirstViewController`;

Please let me know , is that possible ? And how can I do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's only possible when the FirstViewController is active.

Comment: So please tell me how can i go with this

Comment: I don't have experience with `SKPaymentTransaction` class. I use this singleton class for my projects: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

Answer (score 1):

in the `SecondViewController` change the `self` as `observer` to the pointer of the `FirstViewController`, because the instance of `FirsViewController` has the methods.

inside **SecondViewController.m** you must use these lines:

```
- (void)viewdidload {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:firstViewController selector:@selector(productPurchased:)   name:kProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:firstViewController selector: @selector(productPurchaseFailed:) name:kProductPurchaseFailedNotification object: nil];
}
```

**BUT! AND THIS IS THE POINT.**

if the `FirstViewController` is already a valid and loaded view controller in the memory with the methods as you've mentioned above, and it is an observer already for these notifications in the `NSNotificatioCenter`, you don't need to add again it to the `NSNotificationCenter` because the `FirstViewController` can receive and will receive the desired notification still. (it is just not shown, because an other view controller covers it.)

if the `FirstViewController` is not exists yet when the `SecondViewController` is, you cannot reach any instance method called from an another class because the `FirstViewController` was not instantiated before, and you cannot add it to the `NSNotificationCenter` as well.

**CONCLUSION**

it would be better to isolate the purchase callbacks into a third class what you can use for every independent view controller, according to the spirit of the `OOP` and `MVC`.

Answer (score 0):

If your view controllers are the roots of tab-bar controllers, once they are loaded the first time, they stay around unless manually replaced.

Thus, when you install the notification handler in the first controller, unless you remove the notification handler, it will still get them, even when the second controller is onscreen.

Now, it may get unloaded due to memory pressure, or by the custom tab-bar-controller code.  However, it's highly unusual for a tab-bar controller to deallocate one of its view controllers, so your installed notification handlers will be around until you cancel them.

In fact, if both view controllers register for the notifications, then they will both get them.

You are registering in `viewDidLoad` so the first one will get registered immediately, as it will be loaded and displayed as the initial controller.  It will continue to receive those notifications.

When the second one loads, it will also register.  Now both view controllers are receiving the notifications.  When you go back to the first view controller, they will both still be getting the notifications.